# About XCM message execute failed

Tags: xcm

i have a question about xcm message. when i call a xcm transact from the origin parachain, it works well in origin parachain. but in destination parachain , it shows an error : `xcmpQueue.Fail`. how can l solve it?

Comment: Could you please give us some code or more information what you are doing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the link is here :github.com/VegeBun-csj/Asset-Chain. and. github.com/VegeBun-csj/Proof-Chain.    i want to test `ping-pong` pallet which was built in proof chain and asset chain.when i call start function in proof parachain, the mssage was send successfully, but in asset chain it shows xcmpQueue.fail which shows XcmV2TraitsError -> FailedToDecode

Comment: @sjc The link you provided is not enough, you should at least tell us what your XCM configuration is, what the steps that you've taken are, and full details about the error that was shown, including its parameters.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add details to your question. [edit] the question to include the needed information so that it's visible without needing to review the comments.

Answer (score 2):

enable log first and provide more details here and guess you are the person who attach [link here](https://matrix.to/#/!WuksvCDImqYSxvNmua:matrix.parity.io/$q2wcrpEy0flzTR2AEoZcW_hBXwiSAZ7s9RY1l2TEsfw?via=matrix.parity.io&via=matrix.org&via=web3.foundation). If so then better check the transact body encoded correctly(e.g pallet index,call index,call params are as expected as target chain)

Comment: thanks. i am staring two parachain that are proof chain and asset chain.i want to test ping-pong pallet which was built in proof chain and asset chain.when i call `start` function in proof parachain, the mssage was send successfully, but in asset chain it shows `xcmpQueue.fail` which shows `XcmV2TraitsError -> FailedToDecode `.

Comment: the link is here :https://github.com/VegeBun-csj/Asset-Chain. and. https://github.com/VegeBun-csj/Proof-Chain

Comment: the [call](https://github.com/VegeBun-csj/Proof-Chain/blob/c969bb90f6538d425e89ed594b87f21264188eae/pallets/ping/src/lib.rs#L97) in source chain is not the call in target chain, as I mentioned ,you need to encode the dest call correctly or you need to introduce target runtime into the source chain for that